# Rails CSV Dataload in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails 4 app.  A specific table will frequently (monthly) need to be appended with data from a csv file with ~2k records, and each insert will have different records.  I believe I can solve this with a rake task using the CSV class, but if I leave each csv file in the project directory (for client traceability) does this slow down the performance of the container in Production after 'n' months?

Comment: No, the amount of data you are talking about is mostly negligible.

Comment: Do extraneous files (such as a dataload csv) get compiled into the slug/container or is rails smart about that?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with slug/container. Or compiled. The only thing Rails compiles are the assets and there only those files it knows. You would place such CSV files in a different location anyway, not somewhere below /app. I often use a subfolder of /db. You normally have megabytes of images somewhere in /public and this is no problem.